# "INNER JOIN" vs "INTERSECT" performance comparison when dealing with huge amounts of data in Oracle

Tags: query-performance, optimization, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I have two tables with the structure below:

```
create table Table_One
(Ef_date           Date,
Customer_Num      Number,
<Other_Columns>   <Combination of Number/varchar2(50)>);


create table Table_TWO
(Ef_date           Date,
Customer_Num      Number,
<Other_Columns>   <Combination of Number/varchar2(50)>);
```

There is a `Normal index` on the `customer_num` column of both tables and there is a partition on the `ef_date` column. I want to know which query is better in terms of performance when there is a huge amount of data, for instance there are nearly `54,962,020 records added each month`  .

```
QUERY-1:

select Customer_Num
from Table_one 
<Conditions on Other_columns>

    intersect

select Customer_Num
from Table_TwO 
<Conditions on Other_columns>


QUERY-2:

select t1.customer_Num
  from Table_one t1
inner join Table_Two t2
on t1.customer_num = t2.customer_num
```

Comment: I edited your question - but the number of records added each month (which table?) is not important for this question - what **is** important is the number of records in each table at the time of the query! Can you not run an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on both - even seeing the timing of both queries should give you an idea of which runs faster - which I presume is what you want?

Comment: Also, it would greatly depend on the number of unique `Customer_Num` on each table, and if there is a huge number of rows on both tables, the `intersect` would likely take much longer.